# Pytorch neural networks, understanding fully connected layers

Tags: python, pytorch

[image: strong text]

```
def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 3x3 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 3)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 6 * 6, 120)  # 6*6 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
```

From the above image and code from the PyTorch neural network tutorial, I can understand the dimensions of the convolution. How is the output dimension of 'nn.Linear' determined? Also, why do we require three fully connected layers?

Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: The shape of the fc's will be determined by the `forward` layer as it will reveal how are the layers in the arch connected? (Also you want to calculate the output dims of a Conv Layer;

Comment: @Aditya Could you explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: Calculate the output shape post your 2nd Conv2d operation and flatten it to get a single number; That number is the input of the following linear layer :) Refer https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d

Comment: If you mean how 120 and 84 are determined, I would say they are determined by experiences and evaluations . However, there are a few rules of thumbs to determine the hidden units in a linear layer. You may refer to http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part3/section-10.html for more information.

Comment: @whilrun Thank you! That's what I was looking for.